# Checking value is in a list of dictionary values in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of tables coming from a SQLite database:

```py
tbls_name = db_admin.execute(
    """SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"""
)
```

And need to check if `table_name` is in the resulting list of dictionaries.

In Python, I would do:

```py
if table_name in [d['name'] for d in tbls_name]:
```

How can I do this in Jinja?

```
{% set tbl_valid = (table_name in [d['name'] for d in tbls_name]) %}
```

This throws an error.

Note that the `tbls_name` is a list of dictionaries, e.g.:

```py
[
    {'name': 'tableName1'},
    {'name': 'tableName2'},
    {'name': 'tableName3'},
]
```

Comment: If I may ask, why not make `tbls_name` simply a list of names ?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself needing something like that, consider implementing as much logic as possible in Python code.  It's easier and more maintainable.

Comment: @Swifty, How can I do in Jinja? (List of values of dictionaries)

Comment: As @KlasŠ. said, why not implement that part in Python directly; at least it will make it simpler.

Comment: @KlasŠ., I need checking The table user has choose is in the database tables?

Comment: @Swifty, @KlasŠ. In fact because when sending data with form: If user refreshing the page, the `request.form` values are remains and I dont want show the same message to user in every refreshing. AND because if I send data with AJAX fetch, not let me executing `render_template` or `redirect`. This made me remaining in the template and try do this in Jinja.

Comment: Agree with @KlasŠ.  Recently did similar and found it MUCH easier to create a wrapper for `db.execute` that did the heavy lifting rather than try to wrestle with jinja.

Comment: @parmer_110: are you sure tbls_name is a list of dicts as you say? Because from my tests it's a list of sqlite objects, that can be turned to a list of names with: `tbls_name = sum([list(i) for i in tbls_name], start=[])` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter [`rejectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr) for this use case.
If the resulting list of dictionary still contains any item, then the queried table name is valid.

```
{% set tbls_name = [
  {'name': 'foo'},
  {'name': 'bar'},
  {'name': 'baz'},
] -%}
{% set tableName = 'foo' -%}

{% if tbls_name | rejectattr('name', '!=', tableName) | list | length -%}
  table name `{{ tableName }}` is valid
{% endif %}
```

Would yield:

```
table name `foo` is valid
```

Comment: Perfect! TY. Question: What is the - character, near the %} in your Jinja codes?

Comment: @parmer_110 those are [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) characters. In short, they strip whitespace to the right, in this case.